# ng-include works only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot manage to work in Chrome or Edge (not tested in Opera and Safari yet)  `ng-include` directive. I have noticed that is working correctly only in Firefox.

I have a function which loads appropriate template name to $scope var on button ng-click.
Here is a piece of my code:

JS:

```
$scope.loadTemplate = function(url){
      //alert(url);
      $scope.templatePath = url;
      // alert($scope.templatePath);
 };
```

and 
HTML:

```
<md-button class="" style="width:100%; text-align: left;"
                          ng-click="loadTemplate('template1.html')">
                          testButton
                      </md-button>
...

<div ng-include="templatePath"></div>
```

Is there any workaround or solution? i think it is implemented correctly.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Chrome?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only difference is that the div with ng-include is commented: <!-- ngInclude: templatePath -->